# cannot set node_module path for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.3.1
- OS Version: OSX 10.11.6

Steps to Reproduce:

1. I use this script to lazy load nvm/node/npm for zsh. http://broken-by.me/lazy-load-nvm/
2. When I start vscode, it cannot find the library eslint, although it is installed already. Without lazy-load-nvm script, I do not have such a problem.

How can I fix vscode to search in the right path?